# Update owner Change

Tags: custom-object, custom, owner

I have a custom field as previous owner in account lookup to user object

Whenever I modify an account the previous owner field should get updated as account owner.

I tried it using workflow and process builder...but i cant seem to get  it correct

Comment: In Process Builder, you create a new process when a record is changed, you set the object to Account, insert filter criteria if required, and then you insert 'Update Record' as an action. To set new field values 'Previous Owner' for the records you update, you need to use a Field Reference.

Comment: Where exactly do you experience your problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A process builder can do the trick.

[image]

[image]

Here is the Update field Action :

[image]

That should work.

Comment: What is the prior value here?

Comment: The process builder trigger when the Account Owner "Is Changed". By using the formula "PRIORVALUE" you return the "old" OwnerID and update your lookup field with it.
If you have a user A with an id = '123' owner of the account and you change the Account owner to user B with an id = '456', priorvalue of the Owner field will return '123' and update the field you use for previous owner.

Comment: Thanks @RomainCorone for the answer